# Reload sheet in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I am editing a LibreOffice Calc sheet using another program while keeping the sheet open in LibreOffice Calc. Is it possible to refresh LibreOffice Calc so it shows the changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to create a new macro that reloads the content of the sheet by following these steps:

1. Open LibreOffice Calc.
2. Go to *Tools* → *Macros* → *Organize Macros* → *Basic...*
3. In the window that opens, expand *My Macros*, select *Standard*, and click *New*.
4. In the window that opens paste the following (found [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-reload-file-via-macro-on-calc/31458/2)):

   ```vb
   Sub SilentlyReload
       ThisComponent.setModified(False)  'Ignore changes'
       document = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
       dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
       dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Reload", "", 0, Array())
   End Sub
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the macro and close the window.

---

Now try to see if the macro works:

1. Change the content of a file outside of LibreOffice Calc, while having LibreOffice Calc open.
2. Go to *Tools* → *Macros* → *Run Macro...*
3. In the window that opens expand *My Macros*, expand *Standard*, select *Module 1* and click *Run*.

---

Finally, if the macro works and the content is reloaded, you can add it to a shortcut as follows:

1. Go to *Tools* → *Customize...*
2. In the window that opens, select the shortcut you wish to use for the macro, for example <kbd>F3</kbd>, in the *Shortcut Keys* section.
3. In the *Category* section select *LibreOffice Macros* → *My Macros*, expand *Standard*, select *Module 1*.
4. In the *Function* section select *SilentlyReload*.
5. Click *Modify* and then *OK*.

You should now be able to reload your LibreOffice Calc sheet by pressing the <kbd>F3</kbd> key.